Get all named credentials using connectAPI
I am trying to pull the namedcredentials using getNamedCredentials() method in apex but it's not working in anonymous window. This is the error I am getting.
error:
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getNamedCredentials() from the type List<ConnectApi.NamedCredentialList> 

tried this:
ConnectApi.NamedCredentialList nl = ConnectApi.NamedCredentialList.getNamedCredentials();

List <ConnectApi.NamedCredentialList> nl = ConnectApi.NamedCredentialList.getNamedCredentials();

How do I call this method correctly ?
sf article I am following: link

The issue is that you are attempting to call this method on the ConnectApi.NamedCredentialList Class, when the method actually belongs to the ConnectApi.NamedCredential Class.
You should be calling it as:
ConnectApi.NamedCredentialList namedCredList = ConnectApi.NamedCredentials.getNamedCredentials();

The NamedCredentialList has a single property namedCredentials, so to loop through these once you have obtained the entire list, you can simply use the following:
for(ConnectApi.NamedCredential nc : ncList.namedCredentials){
    //Do logic on the named credentials 
}

Alternatively, if you know the Developer Name of the Named Credential you are interested in, you can simply call
ConnectApi.NamedCredential namedCred = ConnectApi.NamedCredentials.getNamedCredential('NamedCredDeveloperName');


Thanks, Callum. How do you loop over namedCredList?

No worries, I've updated my answer with the details of that now.

Named credential is also exposed by SOQL: select id, DeveloperName from NamedCredential
